# Set the button that triggeres a f:converter for JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a a  set in an XHTML for an inputText.  My issue is that when a user clicks Search button, I would expect that it should try the conversion of the f:converter.  However, when I use the "Clear" button I do not want it to try to convert.

Right now when I click the Clear button on my page it is displaying the conversion error if I type in letters, when all it should really be doing is clearing inputText boxes.

Any idea on the cause?  (The error message displays in AJAX).

Ive tried researching online referring to the tag reference:
http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_converter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

1. Use `<h:commandButton type="reset" value="Clear" />` to clear the form on the client side if you don't need to execute any logic on your backing bean. This will save your server from 1 unnecessary request.
2. Add `immediate="true"` to your button to skip the validation phase and execute your logic for clearing the form.

Comment: It seems to be working with both type="reset" or type="clear" - but i do have some code behind for the reset button, I imagine I will need to keep the "submit" action

Answer (score 1):

You should use `immediate="true"` attribute in your Clear button to skip `Process validations` phase. I alwasy [recommend this great article](http://balusc.blogspot.tw/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) of BalusC about JSF lifecycle. And also [this one](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2005/12/28/jsf_component_s_value_local/) from Çağatay Çivici

Comment: can only accept one answer will have to give you upvote